# Why HC-k-regular-(n-even) being NP-Complete implies HC-k-regular is NP complete?

Tags: graphs, np-complete, hamiltonian-circuit

In [1], Corollary 2.3, after proving that HC-k-(n-even) for a fixed k >= 3, the paper says that HC-k-regular being NP Complete is *an inmediate consequence of the former*.

Where:
HC-k-regular-(n-even) means if the graph has a hamiltonian cycle in a k-regular graph with an even number of nodes.

And HC-k-regular means the graph has a hamiltonian cycle in a k-regular graph.

I don't understand how or why "HC-k-regular-(n-even) is NP Complete" implies "HC-k-regular is NP Complete". Why graphs with odd number of nodes are not considered in an explicit way?

---

[1] [Complexity of the hamiltonian cycle in regular graph problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397594901856)

Comment: `inmediate` -> *immediate*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I think by definition "HC-k-regular-(n-even) is NP-Complete" implies "HC-k-regular is NP-hard", since every NP problem can be reduce to an instance of HC-k-regular-(n-even) problem, which is also a HC-k-regular instance. Together with the obvious result that "HC-k-regular is NP", we can get the conclusion "HC-k-regular is NP-Complete".
More intuitively, it's something like "${\sf SAT} \cup 0^n$ is NP-Complete".